# How can I work on a PHP website that only I can access?

Tags: php

I would like to start a website on a production server and am clueless on how to make sure people can't access it while it's being designed.

How could I capture emails/display a coming-soon page while I still work on the site live?

Also where could I find resources to learn about creating developmental PHP servers and updating the live site with dev changes?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: Basic access authentication is one easy option

Comment: `.htaccess` can also do the trick for whitelisting access

Answer (score 2):

Don't put development code on the live server. Do your development and testing on a machine that is not publicly accessible.  The only thing on the public server prior to your launch should be a coming-soon page.

Comment: That's fair enough, but I'm curious once the site is up and live, how can I update the changed files from the dev environment, into the live one?

Comment: Once you're ready to take the site live, you can update it with the code from your dev environment. Just don't do active development on the production server; do it on localhost or a machine on a private network.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .htpasswd and .htaccess files to redistrict access to authorized users